# JSON Data to Form

Tags: json, forms

I am pulling the following JSON to get users current location. I need to fill a form with the individual address elements.

I have been searching high and low and can't find a solution. (I am very new to all of this. I apologize if this is a simple task...

```
    {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "37",
               "short_name" : "37",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Villa Valtelena",
               "short_name" : "Villa Valtelena",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Lake Elsinore",
               "short_name" : "Lake Elsinore",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Riverside County",
               "short_name" : "Riverside County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "92532",
               "short_name" : "92532",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ]
```

Comment: What have you tired.  Post your Javascript and HTML and perhaps we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Alpaca.

http://www.alpacajs.org

It's open-source, Apache 2.0 licensed and can kick out forms from your JSON using Bootstrap, jQuery UI, jQuery mobile or straight up HTML.

I'm one of the committers.  Reach out if you need any help.